# Wrap a Select Statement in a Conditional Statement

Tags: sql-server

What is the best method for creating aliases for the results of a select statement that can have multiple results? I've attempted using a Case statement as well as an If,Then,Else statement but I get syntax errors in all instances.

My base code is as follows:

```
Select e.emp_id as 'EmpId'
,pe.name AS 'Goal Plan Name'
,p.id
,(select top 1 (g.statusid) as 'Status' from goals g
inner join goalassignments ga ON ga.goalid = g.id AND g.typeid IN (1,3,5)
where ga.planid = p.id) 

from plans p  
inner join periods (nolock) AS pe on pe.id = p.periodid 
inner join vgr_emp (nolock) AS e on p.empid = e.emp_id
```

If g.statusid = 1 then I want it to display as "Pending"
If g.statusid = 2 then I want it to display as "Assigned"
However, some will be blank and it renders "Null" in the column.  I want those values to say "No Plan".

Is a case statement best or an if statement? Each one I try I get syntax errors.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Case statement is suitable for your requirement.

Try below:

```
Select e.emp_id as 'EmpId'
,pe.name AS 'Goal Plan Name'
,p.id
,(select top 1 (case when g.statusid=1 then 'Pending' when g.statusid=2 then 'Assigned' when  g.statusid is null then 'No Plan' end) status
from goals g
inner join goalassignments ga ON ga.goalid = g.id AND g.typeid IN (1,3,5)
where ga.planid = p.id) Status
from plans p  
inner join periods (nolock) AS pe on pe.id = p.periodid 
inner join vgr_emp (nolock) AS e on p.empid = e.emp_id
```

**Edit:**

As you let us know your complete criteria, you may want to try below:

```
Select e.emp_id as 'EmpId'
,pe.name AS 'Goal Plan Name'
,p.id
,ISNULL((select top 1 (case when g.statusid=1 then 'Pending' when g.statusid=2 then 'Assigned' end) status
from goals g
inner join goalassignments ga ON ga.goalid = g.id AND g.typeid IN (1,3,5)
where ga.planid = p.id),'No Plan') Status
from plans p  
inner join periods (nolock) AS pe on pe.id = p.periodid 
inner join vgr_emp (nolock) AS e on p.empid = e.emp_id
```

Comment: This has me on the right track! The only one that is not converting is Null.  The value still says Null.

Comment: Make sure it is Null and not "Null". or you may want to check for "Null" instead.

Comment: ugh the Null result is going to be a bugger. I tried with quotes (single and double) and it says its a syntax error but without them it ignores changing it.  I even attempted '' for a blank value but that doesn't work either.

Comment: No I suspect it to be string and not null value. Means if you're storing it as "NULL" and checking for IS NULL then it won't work. You can also try ISNULL(g.statusid,'No Plan'), and it should work if it is null and not 'Null'.

Comment: I attempted "else 'No Plan' " as well and it still does not recognize it.  Basically it's giving me a Null value when it cannot find a goal status.  If I do a count (simply for testing) it brings back zero- so in this case the person does not have any goals therefore there isn't a "top" goal to select.

Comment: I was typing at the same time as your last response.  I tried that as well and i receive the following error:

Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'when'.

Comment: Ahhh thank you for continuing to assist.  the last edit worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

In mysql you can do something like this

```
select concat(if(g.statusid = 1, 'Pending', ''), if(g.statusid = 2, 'Assigned', ''), if(g.statusid is NULL, 'NoPlan', '')), 
e.emp_id as 'EmpId'
,pe.name AS 'Goal Plan Name' ,p.id
    ,(select top 1 (g.statusid) as 'Status' from goals g
    inner join goalassignments ga ON ga.goalid = g.id AND g.typeid IN (1,3,5)
    where ga.planid = p.id) 
from plans p  
inner join periods (nolock) AS pe on pe.id = p.periodid 
inner join vgr_emp (nolock) AS e on p.empid = e.emp_id
```

[mysql flow control](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html)

Comment: I'm using sql server management studio.  i will give this a try as well, however, the other answer had me on the right track with the exception of when its "null".

Comment: Unfortunately I get a ton of errors with the syntax using the above method.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'if'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.